# Stop Windows from displaying a minimized window when I open a similar file

Tags: windows

When I minimize an Excel file to open another Excel file, Windows automatically displays the minimized window again; the one I just minimized. Happens with all Microsoft apps.
Can somebody tell me how to disable this infuriating feature?

Comment: SO is meant for specific programming-related questions and not general support